# Transpile server files recursively with babel

Tags: node.js, babeljs, package.json

My folder structure is such:

```js
functions
-- dist
-- private
-- server
---- controllers
---- middleware
------- clientAuth.js
------- someOtherAuth.js
---- index.js
---- model.js
---- router.js
```

I want to transpile all the .js files in my server folder into .dist. At present in my package.json I have

```js
 "scripts": {
    "prepare": "babel ./server/**/*.js --retain-lines -d ./dist"
  },
```

This only transpiles the files in the subdirectories in server, but not the files in the root of server. What can I use to transpile and place into .dist all the files in the root and the subdirectories?

Comment: if you are only going to have `.js` files in your server, you could replace `./server/**/*.js` with `./server/` and see if that works

Comment: Yep, that worked >.< thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are only going to have `.js` files in your server, you could replace `./server/**/*.js` with `./server/`

So you would end up with

```
"scripts": {
  "prepare": "babel ./server/ --retain-lines -d ./dist"
}
```

in case you still need just the `.js` extension, there should be an `-x` flag to archive that

```
"scripts": {
  "prepare": "babel ./server/ -x '.js'  --retain-lines -d ./dist"
}
```