# Babel recursive transpilation

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

## Scenario

Consider the following directory structure

```
/views
  /one.js
  /two.js
/components
  /Header.js
  /Footer.js
/other
  ...
```

I need to transpile the `/views` directory with Babel. I am doing it programmatically but the equivalent cli command would look like something like this:

`babel views --out-dir .views`

But files in the `/views` directory depend on files in other directories, i.e.

```
/*
  views/one.js
*/

const Header = require('../components/Header');
...
```

Given this dependency, I also need `/components/Header.js` to be transpiled.

## Question

How can I use Babel, possibly with another library, to *only* transpile the specified directory *and* any recursive dependencies *without* transpiling the entire codebase (e.g. `/other`, etc.)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [transpile-server-files-recursively-with-babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601244/transpile-server-files-recursively-with-babel)

Comment: @PriyeshDiukar The referenced question covers glob patterns in the Babel CLI. This question is about transpiling dependencies.

Comment: Sounds like you'd want to reorganize your directory structure so you can easily copy/compile a single root `src` directory or something along those lines.

Comment: Have you heard of webpack, rollup, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably multiple options for getting dependency graphs in Node. You can use [node-dependency-tree](https://github.com/dependents/node-dependency-tree) to get the dependency graph you want to transpile with babel. [Madge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge) would be another possible option (uses `dependency-tree` internally).

[How does it work?](https://github.com/dependents/node-dependency-tree#how-does-this-work)

> Dependency tree takes in a starting file, extracts its declared dependencies via precinct, resolves each of those dependencies to a file on the filesystem via filing-cabinet, then recursively performs those steps until there are no more dependencies to process.

When using `dependency-tree` the `toList` method

> Returns a post-order traversal (list form) of the tree with duplicate sub-trees pruned.
> This is useful for bundling source files, because the list gives the concatenation order.
> Note: you can pass the same arguments as you would to dependencyTree()

The two arguments used by `toList` are

- `filename` The path to the file containing the initial dependency, i.e. the dependency graph's entry point. This is used by the module [`filing-cabinet`](https://github.com/dependents/node-filing-cabinet).
- `directory` The path to all the files, i.e. the root for resolving dependencies. This is also used by the module [`filing-cabinet`](https://github.com/dependents/node-filing-cabinet).

This build script is using CommonJS modules, Node v16.16.0, and Babel 7.19.3. I'm sure you can convert this to ES modules with no issues, or be Promise based if you prefer.

**build.js**

```js
const fs = require('node:fs')
const { dirname, resolve } = require('node:path')
const dependencyTree = require('dependency-tree')
const babel = require('@babel/core')

dependencyTree.toList({
  filename: './views/one.js',
  directory: './views'
}).forEach(path => {
  const basepath = path.split('views/')
  const filepath = resolve('./.views', basepath[1])
  const directory = dirname(filepath)

  fs.mkdirSync(directory, { recursive: true })
  fs.writeFileSync(
    filepath,
    babel.transformSync(fs.readFileSync(path).toString()).code
  )
})
```

```
node build.js
```

Comment: This actually works! Though there's some research I had to do on the `dependencyTree.toList` call could you add what the `directory` and `filename` arguments mean?

Comment: @iggy12345 good idea, I've added a bit of a description for them.